# Dependency Injection (Constructor) with WebForms?

Tags: dependency-injection, webforms, asp.net-4.0

Is this possible with ASP.NET 4.0? In 3.5 it was not.

If it still is not possible has anyone tried injection with a framework like LinFu?

**Update**

I'm specifically asking  about constructor inject in ASP.Net webfroms. In 3.5 it was not possible.

Comment: Dependency Injection (DI) is just a pattern, so I would like some clarity on specifically what doesn't work. I could understand that specific frameworks may have limitations, but even using `Dictionary<string, object>` to resolve objects by key is a (too) simple form of DI, and we know that would work just fine. Using session state is another form of DI. Please clarify.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't think anything relevant has changed in webforms to enable this...

Comment: @Mauricio I figure this was the case. Can you create an answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing new was added in ASP.Net 4.0 to enable constructor injection.

Answer (score 0):

Would [System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227439%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) be what you're looking for?